# Eclipse, change popup text background color when hovering the mouse on a keyword

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-10.04

Ubuntu 10.04.1 new theme has by default all windows background colors set to black.
I don't want to change that.

In Eclipse, the interface didn't change much due to 10.04.1 - except for one annoying thing: 
when the mouse hovers over a keyword - a variable for instance - the type (...) of that keyword is displayed in a small pop-up window.
The problem since 10.04.1, is that the text is in *black* color while the background is *also* black.

Is there a way to change that background color *in Eclipse*?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Update Dec. 2018: as mentioned in [howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53981810/6309), [Eclipse Oxygen 4.7 (June 2017)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/) does now include a way to configure the background color in popups:

See "[Colors in interactive popups](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/platform.php#colors-interactive-popups)"

> Interactive popups like JDT's Quick Outline don't use the platform's tooltip colors any more, since those were sometimes hard to read.

Old style:

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/images/old-popup-color-constants.png]

New style:

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/images/new-popup-color-constants.png]

- Go to `Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts`
- and change the `Basic > Information background` color.

In that same `Colors and Fonts` section, you will find:

> - Code assist
>
>   - `Basic > Content Assist background color` -> change
>   - `Basic > Content Assist foreground color` -> change
> - java doc
>
>   - `Java > Javadoc background` ( overrides default: information background color) -> change

---

Original answer (2010-2012)

All the various popup background color are managed in `Preferences > Java > Editor` (like the one for the completion list popup in [bug 133615](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=133615)).
Other background colors are in `General > Appearance > Colors and Font` (type `background` in the filter field).

But the type popup seems to stick to a system color, which is why you see a black background.
If this is truly the case, it is worth reporting as a bug.

---

The OP confirms it is not the case, actually:

> It was in **`Preferences > C/C++ > Editor > Source hover background`**, and had to untick the "System default" (because the shown color was light-gray!)

---

On Ubuntu 12.04+, the post "[How to change tooltip background color in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity)" also mentions:

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

The recent post (December 2012) "[Eclipse Papercut #10 – Eclipse on Ubuntu: Fixing the black background color in hover](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/12/04/eclipse-papercut-10-eclipse-on-ubuntu-fixing-the-black-background-color-in-hover/)" (from [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/blog/author/vogella/)) confirms:

> The relevant properties are `tooltip_fg_color` and `tooltip_bg_color`.
>   Just search for these values, the position changes sometimes between releases, currently they are at the very top of the file.
>
> The following setting uses more reasonable colors.

```
tooltip_fg_color:#000000
tooltip_bg_color:#f5f5c5
```

---

[pointhi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2967999/pointhi) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571850/eclipse-change-popup-text-background-color-when-hovering-the-mouse-on-a-keyword/3572010#comment65906866_3572010):

> I also had to set the environment variable **`SWT_GTK3=0`** before starting eclipse to get it working.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why I didn't find that after searching for a to-the-nerves time... It was in Preferences > C/C++ > Editor > Source hover background, and had to untick the "System default" (because the shown color was light-gray!)

Comment: Filter for "background" and go to C++ > Editor. Then Look under the list marked "Appearance color options" There you will find "Source hover background"

Comment: I also had to set the enviroment variable `SWT_GTK3=0` before starting eclipse to get it working.

Comment: Since Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) this color can be configured: [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53981810/6505250)

Answer (score 11):

If you use KDE (Kubuntu) you can fix that by changing the Tooltip Background color in KDE System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Colors -> Colors, and change the Tooltip Background.

Comment: +1 for Ubuntu Mint. Under colors select the 'tooltip' colorset and then change the 'inactive text'.

Comment: Sorry, 'Normal Background', not 'inactive text'. And you may or may not have to reload your workspace, which threw me off. Missed my 5 minute window to edit my comment.

Comment: Changing the tooltip background color did not work for me on KDE for CentOS 7. It remained black, even after restarting Eclipse Neon .2.

Comment: Worked for me on KDE Neon 5.12 after restarting Nsight Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

I've adopted a slightly different solution;

First create a new script, eclipse.sh, that starts eclipse, mine look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/eclipse/gtkrc-2.0-eclipse /usr/share/eclipse/eclipse
```

Then create the gtkrc file (/usr/share/eclipse/gtkrc-2.0-eclipse), mine look like this (it have some other changes as well to make better use of the screen):

```
style "my-tooltips"
{
  bg[NORMAL] = "#FFFFAF"
  fg[NORMAL] = "#000000"
}
widget "gtk-tooltip*" style "my-tooltips"

style "gtkcompact" 
{
    font_name="Ubuntu Light 11"

    GtkButton::default_border={0,0,0,0}
    GtkButton::default_outside_border={0,0,0,0}
    GtkButtonBox::child_min_width=0
    GtkButtonBox::child_min_heigth=0
    GtkButtonBox::child_internal_pad_x=4
    GtkButtonBox::child_internal_pad_y=4
    GtkMenu::vertical-padding=1
    GtkMenuBar::internal_padding=0
    GtkMenuItem::horizontal_padding=4
    GtkToolbar::internal-padding=1
    GtkToolbar::space-size=1
    GtkOptionMenu::indicator_size=0
    GtkOptionMenu::indicator_spacing=0
    GtkPaned::handle_size=4
    GtkRange::trough_border=0
    GtkRange::stepper_spacing=0
    GtkScale::value_spacing=0
    GtkScrolledWindow::scrollbar_spacing=0
    GtkExpander::expander_size=10
    GtkExpander::expander_spacing=0
    GtkTreeView::vertical-separator=0
    GtkTreeView::horizontal-separator=0
    GtkTreeView::expander-size=10
    GtkTreeView::fixed-height-mode=TRUE
    GtkWidget::focus_padding=0
    GtkTreeView::vertical-separator = 0
}

class "GtkWidget" style "gtkcompact"

style "gtkcompactextra" 
{
    xthickness=0
    ythickness=0
}

class "GtkButton"   style "gtkcompactextra"
class "GtkToolbar"  style "gtkcompactextra"
class "GtkPaned"    style "gtkcompactextra"
class "GtkNotebook" style "gtkcompact"
```

Comment: What do I do if I don't have root access?

Comment: This is the only solution that works, when --launcher.GTK_version
2 is set in eclipse.ini
P.S. And yes, problem still present in Eclipse Neon.1

Answer (score 2):

window -> preferences -> general -> Appearance -> Color&Fonts -> Java (necessary language, example java) -> Javadoc text color (or Javadoc background)

Answer (score 2):

Since Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) this color can be configured in ***Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*** by changing the ***Basic > Information background color***.

Comment: Thank you (and +1). I have referenced your answer in mine, as well as added links and references.