# How to configure eclipse background color for pop ups in Java Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

In eclipse JDE, when I move my mouse over a Java element, a pop up will show up an with 'Press F2 for focus'. My question is how can I configure the background color of that popup?  I have gone to 'Color and Font' in the preference. I have tried all the ones with 'black' background, but i still can't change the color.

I am using eclipse 3.7M7 on ubuntu 11.04.

Can u please tell me how can I change the color ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse, change popup text background color when hovering the mouse on a keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571850/eclipse-change-popup-text-background-color-when-hovering-the-mouse-on-a-keyword)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity

Answer (score 0):

hey mate I think your having same problem as me. I think this might help 
try installing XulRunner 1.9.2 or later, I think its accordingly  to your version of Firefox 
If I'm not mistaking, well here are the links hope it helps
[xulRunner versions...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158134/firefox-5-6-7-and-xulrunner-which-versions-are-which)

also Im no sure if your doing some gwt but I had an issue with the designer with the BLACK  background anyway this is how you fix it

[Gwt fix for the black background on designer](http://forums.instantiations.com/topic-11-2082.html)