# Firefox 5, 6, 7 and XULRunner: Which versions are which?

Tags: sdk, xulrunner, browser-extension, firefox-5

I'm trying to recompile a Firefox extension that has binary components for use with Firefox 5 now that the beta is out.  According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_5_for_developers#Changes_for_Mozilla_and_add-on_developers) I need to rebuild the binary components.  What I can't figure out is which xulrunner to download and build against from [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/nightly/).

Is there a table that matches up FF versions (5, 6, 7) with code names (Beta, Central, Aurora) with Xul Runner versions (2, etc)?

Any decent guide would be great.

**Update**

It looks like the SDK / Mozilla version number has been changed to match Firefox's version number.  Based on that my guess is now this:

```
Firefox 5 | Beta | XULRunner 5.0
Firefox 6 | Aurora | XULRunner 6.0
Firefox 7 | Central | XULRunner 7.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla's wiki has a section of the [Firefox page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox#Firefox_Release_Tracking) that gives the mappings you're looking for, but it only covers the already-released versions.

Another page called [Releases](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Releases) lists upcoming versions and their codenames, but doesn't indicate the underlying XULRunner version.

It would appear that you'd want "latest-mozilla-beta" (which is listed as XULRunner 5) for now. Judging by the version numbers in the newer nightlies, it looks like the XULRunner versions are going to be shifted so that they match up with their corresponding Firefox versions.

Comment: You are right: the first page is the chart I'm looking for. And, alas, it only goes to Firefox 4.  Hopefully someone will know what that looks like for 5, 6 and 7.

Answer (score 2):

XULRunner version numbers match the version number of the Gecko engine. Firefox 3.6 uses Gecko 1.9.2, Firefox 4 uses Gecko 2.0. It has been recently decided that Gecko version numbers should be identical to Firefox version numbers so Firefox 5 indeed uses Gecko 5.0, Firefox 6 uses Gecko 6.0 and so on. You can get XULRunner nightly builds for unreleased Gecko versions under http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/nightly/ (latest-mozilla-aurora, latest-mozilla-beta and latest-mozilla-central are usually the directories you will be interested in).