# Mouse over for func define in Eclipse, how can I change the font/background color of the pop-up window?

Tags: eclipse

I'm not saying this functionality of Eclipse does not work. It does. When I move the cursor over some local func, a pop-up window shows the definition.

However, I don't know how, this pop-up window is shown with a black background and black character font. You know how it becomes...I cannot see anything! It has been like this since it firstly gets installed. I'm using Ubuntu 8.04 and Eclipse3.5.2 with CDT. I cannot update to Ubuntu11.10. This is another story anyway.

Just wonder where I can specify the color scheme? Guess there should be something in preference to customize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link when I had the same issue.

[Eclipse, change popup text background color when hovering the mouse on a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571850/eclipse-change-popup-text-background-color-when-hovering-the-mouse-on-a-keyword)

**Preferences > C/C++ > Editor > Source hover background, and had to uncheck the "System default" (because the shown color was light-gray!) and then select a color.**