# How do i change background Color of Popups in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[I want to change the background of this box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql8gO.png) but i cant find it in the Options. Can anyone help ? I am using Eclipse Neon v2

Comment: Does this solve your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571850/eclipse-change-popup-text-background-color-when-hovering-the-mouse-on-a-keyword

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse, change popup text background color when hovering the mouse on a keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571850/eclipse-change-popup-text-background-color-when-hovering-the-mouse-on-a-keyword)