# Black text on black window on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

When I move the cursor over an annotation, for example, it opens a window with a black background but also the text is black and therefore it’s not visible, so every time I  have to highlight the text to read it and it is uncomfortable ...
I'm sure there is a setting somewhere but I haven't found it.

See the picture below
[image: Black window eclipse]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53981810/6505250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution is Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> search "Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle" and install the plugin. (Currently is the most popular plugin so you can find it by going to the tab "Popular").